quantreg::summary.rq - is there a way to specify method parameter?
I was using a function rq() from the quantreg package. Originally I fit a model with method="br" and got a warning message that the "solutions may be nonunique". To suppress this warning, I tried fitting a model with different algorithm method="fn" and obtained the following results. However, the summary function on the model object (summary(fit)) yields different coefficients than fit$coefficients. Is there a way to make the summary function output a solution from the "fn" method rather than "br" method?
library(quantreg)

fit <- rq(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, method="fn", data=dat, tau=0.5)
> fit$coefficients
(Intercept)          x1          x2          x3 
  9.4021951  25.1791775  14.1790548   0.2947553 

> summary(fit)

Call: rq(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, tau = 0.5, data = dat, method = "fn")

tau: [1] 0.5

Coefficients:
            coefficients lower bd upper bd
(Intercept)  9.35716      9.07227  9.85734
x1          25.17918     24.63725 26.15980
x2          14.22409     13.87955 14.43724
x3           0.24972     -0.28967  0.55808
Warning message:
In rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ci = TRUE, ...) : Solution may be nonunique

Sample data
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
x1 <- runif(100)
x2 <- sample(0:2, n, replace=TRUE)
x3 <- sample(c(0, 1), n, replace=TRUE)
y <- 10 + 25*x1 + 14*x2 + rnorm(n)
dat <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)


The help page of summary.rq tells you that you can specify the method used to compute standard standard errors when summarising the fit. It also says that "If the initial fitting was done with method "sfn" then use of se = "nid" is recommended."
Which gives you a hint.
library(quantreg)

fit <- rq(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, method="sfn", data=dat, tau=0.5)
fit$coefficients
# [1]  9.4021533 25.1791776 14.1790966  0.2947134

summary(fit, se="nid")
Call: rq(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, tau = 0.5, data = dat, method = "sfn")

tau: [1] 0.5

Coefficients:
     Value    Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)
[1,]  9.40215  0.27335   34.39543  0.00000
[2,] 25.17918  0.41909   60.08057  0.00000
[3,] 14.17910  0.15565   91.09348  0.00000
[4,]  0.29471  0.24546    1.20065  0.23284

summary(fit, se="nid")$coefficients[,1] - coef(fit)
#[1] 0 0 0 0

